# Average a graph of point but not by adding points, in JS

Tags: graph, points, smoothing

I'm working with JavaScript and looking for the right function or math concept that smooths points but does not add points. If I had an array of points like [1,2,10,4], I'm looking for a result that would give me something like [3,6,8,7]. This way I'm left with a less ridged graph. Most smooth functions curve to point to point adding more points and that is not what I'm after. I basically want to put in x vales and get x modified vales back. Is there a name for this type of function?

Comment: I would call this essentially "interpolation". What it sounds like you want is to fit an approximate line/curve to the given points via something like a least-squares fit, then return the approximation from that fit at the original points, which will not necessarily exactly match the given input...

Comment: Sounds like you understood the task but so far interpolation is not helping my search.

Comment: Looks like d3.js does this sort of thing but it makes charts and I just need to do the math as I have a chart creator. http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/smoothing-out-lines-in-d3js.html